# Maven/Eclipse - Updating project to Java7 screws up source folders

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a Maven project in Eclipse, currently running Java 1.6.  I would like to update the project to run Java 1.7.

(Eclipse is Juno 4.2.1. I have to use this build because I'm using RDi.)

After some research, here is what I did:

**1. Updated pom.xml with the new maven-compiler-plugin.**

Was:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is now:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**2. Edited JRE in Java Build Path.**

- From the menu, Project > Properties > Java Build Path.
- Highlight JRE System Library and Edit.
- Was "JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]",
- Is now "JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]".

**3. Maven > Update Project.**

So before, my project was laid out correctly (for Maven).  Now it shows an extra src folder in addition to the src/main/jave package.

Oh, and nothing works. IE: it does not resolve any internal methods.

Before:

[image]

[Edit] More detail on the before:

[image]

[Edit] How `resources` is configured in the pom.

[image]

[Edit] Java Build Path

[image]

After:

[image: after screen shot]

After problem log:

Comment: What are some of the compile errors you have now? The "After" layout actually looks correct, not the "Before" one.

Comment: Does **cleaning** help? Have you checked the actual errors? Maybe you lost some other library, or there is some genuine compile error in your program now?

Comment: Copy the error text from "Problems" view in Eclipse please. If not visible, use "Show view" rubmenu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check if you've jdk1.7 installed? If that's the case, you can point to it from your Eclipse.

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add
```

Browse to your Java 7 installation and select it. Then you might have to edit the JRE in your Build Path again.

Comment: Apparently this is step 4.

Answer (score 1):

We can't see what your `.classpath` (ie, the Java Build Path) looked like before, but based on your screen shot it was *not* a typical Maven project layout; it shows `src/` as the only Source Location (Eclipse terminology) but should normally show `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java`, and `src/test/resources` as in your "After" screen shot. The extra display of `src` in your After screenshot is just Eclipse showing the physical folder structure; nothing wrong there.

I guess you had not properly configured your Eclipse project settings with the pom configuration before, which is why it looks strange to you now. But what you have now looks correct.

Comment: I do have the package / folder layout you're referring to. I've added another expanded screenshot plus a pic of how `resources` is configured in the pom. `/src/main/java` is at the top, `/resources`, and `/src/main/test` follows. (And yes, it's a whole project full of tests.)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project

```
Project>Clean..
```